# I have a NVIDIA Quadro 2000 graphic card, and I want to install TensorFlow. Will it work?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, nvidia

I know Quadro 2000 is CUDA 2.1.
My PC specs as follows:

- Quadro 2000 with 16GB RAM.
- Xeon(R) CPU   W3520 @2.67GHz  2.66GHz
- Windows 10Pro.

I want to use **Tenserflow** for Machine Learning, and Deep Learning.

Let me know a little in-depth, as I am a beginner.

Comment: No, it won't....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system is eligible to use TensorFlow but not with GPU because that requires GPU  a having compute capability more than 3.0, and your GPU is only a compute capability 2.1 device.

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25).

If you want to use GPU for training you can use some free resource available on the internet

1. colab - https://colab.research.google.com/
2. kaggle - https://www.kaggle.com/
3. google GCP - https://cloud.google.com/ - get free 300$ resource for 1 year validity

Comment: I'm learning TF and exploring my knowledge, Thanks for the help. And, also working on colab will be just as TF? Because, I will be migrating to a better GPU sooner the possible, at that time I don't wanna start learning TF all over again.

Comment: There is only one tensorflow available for ML so, both are absolutely same. colab is just an platform to train your model any framework or packages you might need, can be  installed there. It is a Jupiter notebook same available for offline use.

Comment: I have installed a virtual environment using conda installed a CPU version of TensorFlow to use on Visual Studio IDE.
Will this work to use basic tensor flow applications as a learner and beginner?